# Why am I getting "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open" when trying to save an image through multer's storage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I'm trying to use multer to save an image to my back-end, and more specifically, to `public/images/servers` folder. Sadly I get an error:

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\MAMP\htdocs\Chat Backend\public\images\servers\2020-08-07T12:33:31.556Z-aohan-chen-.jpg'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\MAMP\\htdocs\\Chat Backend\\public\\images\\servers\\2020-08-07T12:33:31.556Z-aohan-chen-.jpg',
  storageErrors: []
}
```

I'm not sure why it says that there is no such file or directory when everything up until here exists - `'C:\MAMP\htdocs\Chat Backend\public\images\servers'`. The only thing left is for multer to save the image in the servers folder.

```
var multer = require('multer');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'public/images/servers')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + '-' + file.originalname)
    }
})

var fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if (file.mimetype === 'image/png' || file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' || file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg') {
        cb(null, true)
    } else {
        cb(null, false)
    }
}

app.use(multer({ storage: storage, fileFilter: fileFilter }).single('image'));
```

Comment: Some characters are not allowed to be used in a filename (ex. colon).

Comment: @Teemu I don't think that's the issue because I just hardcoded 'test' as a filename and I still got the error.

Comment: @Bobimaru maybe your path for the storage is not okay. I was in a similar situation as you.